RDP Windows pop-ups hiding behind parent RDP window when clicking on another RDP session on another monitor
I am hosting multiple remote desktop connections using the Remote Desktop Connections app. I have one session on each monitor (two monitors, two sessions). If I bring up a pop-up window within each session (each session now has a parent window and a child window), and click back & forth between the two session pop-up windows on each monitor, the RDP pop-up window of one of the sessions will hide behind all currently opened windows (local windows and the remote parent window) on that monitor.
Seeing this problem in Windows 11 machines, and RDP sessions are hosted on MS Windows Server 2019 (64-bit)
I tried opening two sessions, one on each monitor. I opened a pop-up window on each session. Clicking on the pop-up window on a monitor, results in the pop-up window on the other monitor getting placed behind all other currently opened windows on that monitor.
If on monitor 1, I have Chrome open, and both the RDP window and its pop-up open on top, clicking on the RDP session on monitor 2, will put the RDP session on monitor 1, in the back behind Chrome and any other open windows.
I would need both sessions to stay in the front as I click back and forth between RDP sessions.

What popup are you talking about? I think some images may help us better understand what you're talking about.

This is very confusing.

See this similar issue 2017/2018 thread regarding Win10: W10 1709 RemoteApp - Pop-ups hidden behind main window Maybe try MSRDC as alternative to MSRDP
